# Prepare image data for tflearn

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, preprocessor, tflearn

I have a few thousand pictures I want to train a model with `tflearn`. But somehow I have some problems to prepare the images to the right data format. I tried `tflearn.data_utils.image_preloader()` but I'm getting a `ValueError`. So I tried to write my own `image_loader.py` file, but with so many pictures my RAM is running full.

Does anyone know a good tutorial, example or anything to write a CNN with my own image set, along with details on how to preprocess the data for `tflearn`?

Comment: I just was facing a similar problem. After processing my images where not in `uint8` format. I casted them and now `tflearn` works well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) is a good place to start. Preprocessing is covered in [this section](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#model-inputs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how neural nets are working therefore the Tensorflow tutorial has now use for me. Also the preprocessing section is not useful, because in all examples they are using pre made data sets which are pickeled. I want to preprocess my own set of pictures and for that problem I'm not finding any solution.

Comment: In my experience, I actually preprocess the images using numpy and literally save the processed images to disk.